# How to get proper special character from string in java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer, jdom-2

1. I am setting a special character in DataModel. 
   My DataModel

   ```
   public class LaunchModel implements Serializable {

       private List<LaunchModel> testquestionList;
       public LaunchModel() {
       testquestionList=new ArrayList<LaunchModel>();
       }
       //GETTER AND SETTER
   }
   ```

   My controller method..

   ```
   private void setdefaultValues() {

       LaunchModel temp=new LaunchModel();
       List<LaunchModel> tempList=new ArrayList<LaunchModel>();
       temp.setQuestion("ΔLMN and ΔXYZ");
       tempList.add(temp);
       this.launchModel.setTestquestionList(tempList);
   }
   ```

   My JSP page..

```
<h:form id="addAssessmentFormId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <t:div id="main" forceId="true">
        <t:dataList id="questionList" var="question"
            value="#{launchPlayer.launchModel.testquestionList}" rowIndexVar="index"
            layout="unorderedList" forceId="true">

            <t:div>
            <h:outputText id="que" value="#{question.question}" />
                <h:inputTextarea id="que" value="#{question.question}" />
            </t:div>
        </t:dataList>
        <t:div style="text-align:center;">
            <h:commandButton value="save" action="#{launchPlayer.testsaveAssessment}"></h:commandButton>
        </t:div>
    </t:div>


</h:form>
```

when it display that time it displays correct special character but when click on save button that time it change the value of String in junk character How it happens I dnt get it.
How to solve this problem.

Comment: it prints like &#916;LMN and &#916;XYZ

Comment: What is your page's character encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set default encoding in your jsp. That should do.

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```